# Formula for number of occurrence of the sorted data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this column with frequently occurring data. I've sorted the unique values and I am looking to calculate the number of occurrence of each individual data.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is:

> - Select the range with all recurring data
> - Copy the data to a new page / location
> - Select the newly pasted data
> - Under the Data tab, click Remove Duplicates
> - Apply the below formula to your list

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
```

Alternatively, if you are filtering the data, you can simply use the same formula on your existing list since you would be filtering out the duplicates anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Create a pivot table. That's what they do.

Comment: Very new to excel so the above answer did the trick. I'll have a look at pivot

Answer (score 0):

First you can use combination of `INDEX(), MATCH()` function to extract unique values from your list. Then use `Countif()` function to count occurrence. To extract use below formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$10),0,0),0)),"")
```

To count occurrence use following formula.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,C2)
```

[image]

> Alternatively you can use `Advance Filter` method to extract unique values then use `COUNT()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Being that you already have the unique values, the answer to your question is to use the `COUNTIF` formula.

`=COUNTIF(A:A,C2)` then drag down

The assumptions (which are consistent with your screenshot) for the formula are:

Column A has your base data with the multiples in it

Column C has your unique values and they start on row 2

The formula is pasted into D2 and dragged down